# How to Decode A Binary Read from Kafka Using Avro C library?

Tags: c, decode, avro

I was able to use the Java API to decode the binary that is read from Kafka as there is `BinaryDecoder` from the `DecoderFactory`. I am trying repeat this using the C API.

However, no luck so far. It is straightforward to set values and then get values (schema and data are bond with each other). In the case where the encoded data is put into Kafka, we need to decode the data using a provided schema. Can you anyone shed some light on how to do this using the C API? Thanks a lot!

For example, we will get the following encoded data from Kafka

`" site_visit^Z111.222.333.444^@^T1446231845^@^N1209600^@^F1.0"`

and we have the schema available (separated from the data above, as we do using Java):

I want to the decoded data to be:

```
{"segment_name": "site_visit", "ip_address": "111.222.333.444", "received_at": "T1446231845", "ttl": "1209600", "probability": "1.0"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libserdes](https://github.com/confluentinc/libserdes) for this purpose. There are examples (serdes-kafka-avro-client.c, kafka-serdes-avro-console-consumer.cpp) how to get such JSON result.